Are there compact metric spaces with Hausdorff measure equal to 0 or infinty
I am looking for examples of non-empty metric spaces which are compact with Hausdorff dimension $\alpha$, and have either
its $\alpha$-dimensional Hausdorff measure equal to $0$
or
its $\alpha$-dimensional Hausdorff measure equal to $\infty$.
Without compactness, examples with the second propery are easy to find, as the real line has dimension $1$, but $1$-dimensional measure equal to $\infty$. That's why I added compactness.
(I assume that this question has already been asked on this site, but I could not find it ...)

the space with one point

@pancini: Wikipedia says "The zero-dimensional Hausdorff measure is the number of points in the set". If we adopt this convention, then your counter-example does not work since the space with one point has then measure 1.

... but I realize that the empty set could be a problem ... I will fix the question to exclude the empty set.

See Gerald Edgar's answer to Construction of null sets with prescribed Hausdorff dimension and generalizations and my answer to Existence of dimension function (i.e., exact gauge function).

@Cosine you're right; my mistake.

It might be possible with $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, if you try different metrics on it. Given $a\in (0,\infty)^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\gamma>0$ put $d_{a,\gamma(x,y)}=a_{\min\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid x(n)\neq y(n)\}}2^{-\gamma\min\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid x(n)\neq y(n)\}}$. If $a_n2^{-\gamma n}> a_m2^{-\gamma m}$ for $n<m$, then this defines a metric generating the product topology on $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. If $a_n$ is bounded by a polynomial in $n$ then the Hausdorff dimension of $d_{a,\gamma(x,y)}$ is $\frac{1}{\gamma}$. If you choose $a_n=n$ for sufficiently large $n$ then the measure will be infinite and if you choose $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ for sufficiently large $n$ then the measure will be zero. Of course some details have to be filled in, but I hope this will work.
